# What is the rigorous meaning of conditional convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $Y,X_1,X_2,\dots$ be real random variables on probability space, and suppose that $X_n\Rightarrow N(0,1)$ as $n\to \infty$ (weak convergence). What does it mean when someone writes that, conditional on $Y$, we have $X_nY\Rightarrow N(0,Y^2)$ as $n\to \infty$?

Am familiar with the concept of regular conditional distribution, but not sure how to formalize the statement using this.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: If you knew $Y=y$ then it would be reasonable to say $X_nY$ converged in distribution to $N(0,y^2)$.  Talking about "conditional on $Y$" is essentially the same, but without specifying the particular value of $Y$

Comment: I think some independence ($Y$ independent of $\{X_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$) is needed.

Comment: @Henry Yes but the $X_n$ might not be dependent of $Y$. Does it makes sense to fix $Y=y$ without taking into account the impact on $X_n$?

Comment: I would rather interpret that statement as the convergence of the joint distribution of the random vector $(X_n Y, Y)$. That is, $(X_n Y, Y)$ converges in distribution to $(Z,Y)$ where the conditional distribution of $Z$ given $Y=y$ is $\mathcal{N}(0, y^2)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Ok but  $(X_n Y, Y)\Rightarrow (Z,Y)$ does not follow from $X_n\Rightarrow X$ no?

Comment: What you mentioned is correct, but the convergence in your posting is *conditioned on $Y$*. To me, the statement that '$X_n\Rightarrow X$ conditioned on $Y$' sounds the same as telling that $$\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)\mid Y] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)\mid Y],$$ in an appropriate sense, for any bounded Borel functions $f$, borrowing the idea of Portmanteau theorem. I believe that this will imply the joint convergence of $(X_n,Y)\Rightarrow(X,Y)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee From https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4187044/522332 we have that $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)\mid Y] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)\mid Y]$ for all $f\in\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbb{R})$ implies $X_n \Rightarrow X$, but am not sure about $(X_n,Y)\Rightarrow(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y$ and $\{X_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are independent, then for any $f\in\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbb{R})$

$$E[f(X_nY)]=E\big[E[f(X_nY)|\sigma(Y)]\big]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Big(\int_\mathbb{R} f(xy)\mu_n(dx)\Big)\,\mu_Y(dy)$$
where $\mu_n$ is the distribution of $X_n$ and $\mu_Y$ is the distribution of $Y$.

By assumption $X_n\Rightarrow N(0;1)$ and so, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(xy)\mu_n(dx)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(xy)e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2}}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}|y|}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)e^{-\tfrac{t^2}{2y^2}}\,dt$$
The rest is dominated convergence.

Comment: If am not mistaken you showed that $\mu_{X_n}\otimes \mu_Y$ converges weakly to  $\mu_{X}\otimes \mu_Y$. This is an unconditional convergence statement no?

Comment: That follows as a consequence. But what we have is that $E[f(X_nY)|\sigma(Y)]\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} \Phi_{0,y^2}f$, where $\Phi_{0,y^2}$ is the Gaussian distribution (kernel) with mean $0$ and variance $y^2$. Without independence, I don't think you can say much about $\mu_n(dx, y)=P[X_n\in dx| Y=y]$. Or maybe, you are in the situation described by Sangchul Lee (first comment) above.

Comment: So if we define $\kappa:\Omega\times \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\to[0,1]$ by $\kappa(\omega,A)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}|Y(\omega)|}\int_{A}\exp\big\{{-\tfrac{t^2}{2Y(\omega)^2}}\big\}\,dt$, then $\kappa$ is a markov kernel such that $E[f(X_nY|Y]\to \int f(t)\, d\kappa(\omega,\cdot)$ a.s.? I believe the measurability of $\omega\mapsto \kappa(\omega,A)$ is a consequence of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: I would define the kernel $W(a,dx)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\tfrac{t^2}{2a}}\,dt$. Then $\kappa(\omega,A)=W(Y^2(\omega),A)$. Measurability follows from the measurability of $W$ and the measurability of $Y^2$. But in senescence, the argument you gave works fine.